# What should I do if tar have no "-I" option?

Tags: linux, tar, solaris

I found "-I" option of tar is only availbe for Solaris, and no countpart in Linux machine, what should I do to realize same operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU tar equivalent of the Solaris `-I` option is the `-T` (or `--files-from`) option.